# How to prevent perl to replace unix-only linefeeds?

Tags: perl, batch-file, activeperl

I have a small routine where I apply some regex over a file and write the whole content to a new file.

```
perl -p -e "myRegexReplace" %INPUT% >%OUTPUT%
```

The script is executed on a windows machine.

For testing purpose, I have a file that only contains Unix Linebreaks `LF`. However, after processing the file the linebreaks are `CRLF` format.

How can I prevent perl from changing the linefeed format?

Update @ amon:

```
STDIN :unix
STDIN :crlf
STDOUT :unix
STDOUT :crlf
```

Comment: it's a regex to replace a date, like `([0-9]{2})-+([0-9]{2})-+([0-9]{4})`. Also if I take the regex out and just let perl "parse" the file the LF feeds are also changed.

Comment: Are you using ActivePerl?

Comment: yes I'm using ActivePerl

Comment: There is a setting but it's probably broken: http://bugs.activestate.com/show_bug.cgi?id=33289

Comment: **Strawberry Perl** has the same "bug"

Comment: Perl includes PerlIO-layers which do automatic line ending translation. It seems like STDOUT has the `:crlf` layer. Please give me the output of `perl -E "for my $fh (STDIN, STDOUT){say qq($fh :$_) for PerlIO::get_layers($fh)}"` so that we can see what exact layers are currently activated. I can then provide code to remove this unwanted layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the PerlIO-documentation:

> #### :crlf
>
> A layer that implements DOS/Windows like CRLF line endings.  On read converts pairs of CR,LF to a single "\n" newline character.  On write converts each "\n" to a CR,LF pair.  Note that this layer will silently refuse to be pushed on top of itself.
>
> It currently does not mimic MS-DOS as far as treating of Control-Z as being an end-of-file marker.

So on output, the LF gets converted to the unwanted CRLF.

To remove this layer, we want to get the raw filehandle without byte munching. This script demonstrates how to use `binmode` to change layers:

```
use feature 'say';

print_layers();

# remove any byte-munching layers (:crlf, :utf8)
# this would also be a nice place to add `:utf8` or some `:encoding(...)`
binmode $_, ":raw" for STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR;

print_layers();

sub print_layers {
  say "== Layers ==";
  for my $fh (STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR) {
    say "$fh :$_" for PerlIO->get_layers($fh);
  }
}
```

The output should be:

```
== Layers ==
STDIN :unix
STDIN :crlf
STDOUT :unix
STDOUT :crlf
STDERR :unix
STDERR :crlf
== Layers ==
STDIN :unix
STDOUT :unix
STDERR :unix
```

I couldn't quite figure out how to convince the `open` pragma to do this for me.

Comment: Is there a way to pop off just the `:crlf`?

Comment: @TheDoctorWhat you can try “adding“ the `:pop` layer like `binmode $fh, ':pop'`. This will remove the uppermost layer. It might be safer to record all current layers, apply the `:raw` layer, and then reapply all layers except `:crlf`: `binmode $fh, ":$_" for 'raw', grep { $_ ne 'crlf' } PerlIO->get_layers($fh)`. Be sure to check via `PerlIO->get_layers($fh)` that you've actually achieved the wanted layer composition.

Answer (score 1):

simply piping to `tr`:

```
perl -p -e "myRegexReplace" %INPUT% | tr -d \r >%OUTPUT%
```

tr download: [GNUWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm), [UnxUtils Updates](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)